# Mac M1: Error: Protocol error (Target.setDiscoverTargets): Target closed while starting aws-azure-login

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to configure AWS login using aws-azure-login (https://github.com/sportradar/aws-azure-login) in Mac with configuration of M1 chip running MacOs 12.1 Monterey.

Upon running `docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws sportradar/aws-azure-login --profile default`, I get the below error,

```
Error: Protocol error (Target.setDiscoverTargets): Target closed.
    at /aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:71:63
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.send (/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:70:16)
    at Function.create (/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser.js:117:26)
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Launcher.js:103:56)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Object._performLoginAsync (/aws-azure-login/lib/login.js:461:23)
    at async Object.loginAsync (/aws-azure-login/lib/login.js:324:30)
```

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/sportradar/aws-azure-login/issues/166? Not just the 'headline'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue with M1. You need to configure both `aws-azure-login` and aws cli separately for M1.

You can follow below steps,

1. `npm install -g aws-azure-login`
2. `aws-azure-login --configure`
3. `aws-azure-login --profile profile_name`
4. `docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws sportradar/aws-azure-login --configure --profile profile_name`

Make sure profile_name already added in aws config i.e. ~/.aws/config.